# How to take numbers and words out of a txt file and assign them to int and char*

Tags: c

I am making a text based game and want the user to be able to save.  When they save all the variables will be saved to a text file.

I can't figure out how to take them out of the file and assigning them to specific variables and pointers.

The file will look somewhat like this:

```
jesse
hello
yes
rifle
0
1
3
20
```

Is there anyway I can specify what line I want to take out with fscanf?  Or do I have to take a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify what line to read from because the concept of a file stream in C does not explicitly distinguish new lines. They are simply treated as a character. To read from a specific line, you would have to loop forward with `fseek` and `fgetc` until you find `'\n'` at which point you can update some variable that holds the current line number the stream points to.

One way around this would be to have information at a fixed offset. For example, say you are storing player information then if you make player information a fixed size X and have the constituent data at fixed indexes into each structure, you can just `fseek` to the right location straight away.

However, if you have structured data, it may be more suitable to use a format which is able to represent these structures inherently such as XML or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Altough I can't exactly tell what you want, I'd do a few suggestions:

- Use a SQLite file instead of a text file. This way you can use SQL to get exactly what you want. Shortcut for you: http://www.sqlite.org/
- If you still want to use a text file, use it comma-separated instead of spaces-separated. It's more common of a practice.

Comment: k thx idk SQL though... so seperate them with commas. Sorry i guess i am not being clear. Lets say someone has 2 health left in the game, i want to save 2 to the file so next time they come on there health will be at 2. i also want to store there name in the file so how basically how do i read things from a file and store diff things in diff variables. Sorry i am terrible at describing this lol

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple settings reader for my C program, maybe it might be useful to you to know how to parse test files
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8620/coding-style-in-c